# operator may trap for inferred type. Motoko Nat

Tags: motoko

I have written this simple Motoko code but when I deploy my canister I get a warning stating **operator may trap for inferred type. Motoko Nat**

```
    import Debug "mo:base/Debug";
    actor DBank {
      var currentValue = 300;
      currentValue := 100;
    
      public func topUp(amount: Nat) {
        currentValue += amount;
        Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
      };
    
      public func withdraw(amount:Nat) {
        let tempValue = currentValue - amount;
        if(tempValue>=0) {
          currentValue -= amount;
        Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
        } else {
          Debug.print("amount too large, not enough balance")
        }
        
      };
    }
```

I'm using the candid UI to call my function, my code is working fine but I can't get rid of the warning, can anyone help me, with how to remove the warning

in the image below the error is referring to the line :

> let tempValue = currentValue - amount;

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both operands to the subtraction `currentValue - amount` are of type Nat, the subtraction is performed at type Nat. That implies that the result would be out of bounds if it became negative, and you'd get a trap. The test on the next line would never be reached. So the warning is there for a reason. :)

(Edit: FWIW, the warning actually reads "operator may trap for inferred type Nat", it's just wrapped around oddly in Candid UI.)

I'd suggest changing the function to:

```
      public func withdraw(amount : Nat) {
        if (amount <= currentValue) {
          currentValue -= amount;
          Debug.print(debug_show(currentValue));
        } else {
          Debug.print("amount too large, not enough balance");
        }
      };
```

Edit 2: The other solution would be to force the subtraction to be be performed at type Int by adding a type annotation:

```
let tempValue : Int = currentValue - amount;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, both of the ways work. I read the documentation regarding type casting, but I like how the 1st solution works without using tempValue